# Error with mustache and jquery?

Tags: jquery, widget, mustache

I am using mustache within a jquery widget calling external json/template. My Jquery seems fine. however mutstache is giving me a error.
Script as follows:

> TypeError: this.tail.search is not a function
>   [Break On This Error]

```
var match, pos = this.tail.search(re);

(function() {

// Localize jQuery variable
var jQuery;

/******** Load LAB Js *********/

    var script_tag = document.createElement('script');
    script_tag.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
    script_tag.setAttribute("src",
        "js/LAB.min.js");//local
    if (script_tag.readyState) {
      script_tag.onreadystatechange = function () { // For old versions of IE
          if (this.readyState == 'complete' || this.readyState == 'loaded') {
              scriptLoadHandler();
          }
      };
    } else { // Other browsers
      script_tag.onload = scriptLoadHandler;
    }
    // Try to find the head, otherwise default to the documentElement
    (document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement).appendChild(script_tag);

/******** Load js as required ******/
function scriptLoadHandler() {
    var labjs = $LAB
    .script('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js').wait()
    .script('js/mustache.js').wait();//local
    labjs.wait(function(){
        main();
    });  
}

/******** main function ********/
function main() { 
    jQuery = window.jQuery.noConflict(true);

    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        function jsonHandler(data){
            $.get('templates/template.html',function(template){
                console.log(data);
                console.log(template);
                var htmlRenderer = Mustache.to_html(template,data);
            });
        }

        $.getJSON('json/data.json',jsonHandler);                




    });
   //alert('end');
}//main() done

})();//function done
```

Comment: which is the browser used?

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue when I accidentally switched the template string and object parameters.
It is supposed to be: `Mustache.render("{{name}} template works like this", { name: "Mustache" });`

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same problem with jquery 1.8.x. I solved it by render the html-template as string not as html object. With dataType: 'text' you will get a clean string with html content of your template. The render engine works fine with it.
Tested with: firefox and chrome

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: './htmlTemplates/conferenceMembers.htpl',
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function (data) {
            $(divId).append(Mustache.render(data, htmlRenderValues));
        }
    });
```

Note: This problem is gone with jquery 2.0.1. Render on html Object works.

Comment: For the purpose of simpleness, I almost use exclusively `$.get`instead of `$.ajax`(as the original asker did in his question). Thus, I find more convenient just adding the `'text'`parameter as in `$.get('./htmlTemplates/conferenceMembers.htpl',function(data){...},'text');`

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error in Firefox, but strangely not Chrome. It turns out it was due to the template data being `False` when running `mustache.render()`.

Turns out the project already had code to cater for this written by somebody else which I found after much pain to allow other components to check when templates were loaded:

htmltemplate.js:

```
function HTMLTemplate(location)
{
    this.template = null;
    var self = this;
    $.get(staticURL+location, function(data)
    {
        self.template = data;
    });

}

HTMLTemplate.prototype.getTemplate = function()
{
    if(this.template)
    {
        return this.template
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

mediabootstrap.js:

```
var MediaBootstrap = {};
MediaBootstrap.templates = {};
MediaBootstrap.init = function()
{
    this.templates.mytemplate = new HTMLTemplate('js/templates/mytemplate.html');
}

MediaBootstrap.templatesLoaded = function()
{
    var loaded = true;
    for(key in this.templates)
    {
        if(!this.templates[key].getTemplate())
        {
            loaded = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return loaded;
}
```

myobject.js:

```
MyObject.buildOptions = function(data)
{
    if(!MediaBootstrap.templatesLoaded())
    {
        setTimeout(function(){
            MyObject.buildOptions(data);
        }, 100);
        return;
    }
    var tpl = MediaBootstrap.templates.mytemplate.getTemplate();
    var html = Mustache.render(tpl, data);
    this.element.find('div.container').html(html);
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand why Chrome was working without this, maybe it's somehow more efficient at loading the templates faster?